# NiFi: Can I get variables in NiFI on REST API?

Tags: rest, api, apache-nifi

Can I get 'variables' in NiFI on REST API?

I found to get variables in NiFi's rest api document, but I do not found.

variables is :
[image]

is it provided?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a `GET` request to `/process-groups/{id}/variable-registry` where `{id}` is the process group ID you are interested in. You will receive a JSON response similar to:

```
{
    "processGroupRevision": {…},
    "variableRegistry": {
        "variables": [{
            "variable": {
                "name": "value",
                "value": "value",
                "processGroupId": "value",
                "affectedComponents": [{…}]
            },
            "canWrite": true
        }],
        "processGroupId": "value"
    },
    "disconnectedNodeAcknowledged": true
}
```

This is all documented on the [Apache NiFi REST API page](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html) under *Process Groups*. You can also use your browser's developer tools panel to inspect the requests that the NiFi UI makes to the server as you interact with the UI to observe what calls are made.

Answer (score 2):

You can also easily fetch these using the [Community NiFi Python Client: NiPyApi](https://github.com/Chaffelson/nipyapi)

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 03:03:55) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
>> import nipyapi
# Get your ProcessGroup object
>> pg = nipyapi.canvas.get_process_group('myProcessGroup')
# Get the VariableRegistry for that ProcessGroup
>> vars = nipyapi.canvas.get_variable_registry(pg)
>> vars.variable_registry.variables
[{'can_write': True,
 'variable': {'affected_components': [],
              'name': 'foo',
              'process_group_id': 'fb88a5cb-0164-1000-d5ce-d89ad0e93df2',
              'value': 'bar'}}]
```